# Is it possible to interact with Gmail using AJAX (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, html, gmail

I would like to build my own interface for gmail, by programatically interacting with the actual Gmail service and pipe all requests on my service to gmail itself.

The user would have to login to his or her gmail account, after which my app needs to be able to interact with the gmail service.

Is there an API available for Javascript that would allow me to do this?

Any other related feedback is appreciated as well. Thanks.

Update: one site that might have done what I am trying to do would be otherinbox.com, unless they proxy all e-mail through their own servers (this is something I do not wish to do, as I want people to interact with gmail directly through a Javascript API).

Comment: Your site hosted on abc.com cannot make AJAX requests to *.google.com. You'll need to proxy it from your domain.

Comment: I guess the only way would be to create a bridge for a signed java applet. How ugly.

Comment: So how are chrome extensions able to interact with gmail. Most are free. One being: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-from-gmail-by-google/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher They can send email for you, tell how many unread messages etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do everything you want as a browser plugin on top of Gmail, by monitoring and observing what goes on, you might want to take a look at this. It won't quite do what you're asking for, but it gets you somewhere along the path.

[Gmailr](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/02/05/introducing-gmailr-an-unofficial-javscript-api-for-gmail/)

Unfortunately, you're probably going to need a server. Even if you could work around the cross-domain issues, Gmail's interface is basically built dynamically with JavaScript when the page loads. So the JavaScript function names will be changing on you literally all the time.

Just about everybody doing anything like what you're describing (we provide an alternative interface to Gmail as well at [emailga](http://emailga.me)) has gone this route. I know the OtherInbox guys as well, and they have a server component that uses the IMAP interface to do most of their magic.

Comment: That's the final confirmation I need. Unfortunately having a server in between is not an option for me due to bandwidth and it being a free service.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at [Gmail API](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/).

I think you can work with it, although, I haven't investigated it in depth.

hope it helps.

Comment: I'm afraid it's meant for client or server sided applications. It looks like I'll have two major issues. 1) the need for cross domain requests 2) processing IMAP/SMTP in Javascript on the browser

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately you are right there no Javascript API for Gmail. cross domain requests could be handled using I frame proxy. http://www.codecouch.com/2008/10/cross-site-scripting-xss-using-iframes/ for example and explanation.

Comment: Looks like it requires the target domain to integrate a frame with my domain.

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to create a custom mail server which can connect to gmail via **pop3 or imap or smtp**. 
on the other hand i am sure that ajax requests cannot be cross domain requests, but the php can do this. so you must need a php file wich access to the gmail through pop3|imap|smtp or ajax. but only javascript cant do that.

Comment: It looks like I need an OAuth STMP/IMAP Javascript library. This might be possible with WebSocket. Not sure. What you suggested is an intermediary server, which unfortunately is no option for me.

Comment: because you want to use ajax, and you cant make a remote ajax request (cross domain request)

i dont kow how websockets are working , but i am not sure this will.